# How to verify if server can make outbound requests on port 80 and 443?

Tags: apache, outbound, port80

In relation to [this question on an openid issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448072/openid-with-domain-mp) I'm having, someone asked me to check whether my server is able to make outbound requests on port 80 and 443.

Can you tell me how to verify that? The server is:

```
Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.8
```

More info via php_info() [here](http://70.38.38.144/~extranet/info.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify it by trying to fetch a webpage on some other server (e.g., Google) using php's curl functions. Port 80 is HTTP, port 443 is HTTPS.

Comment: ok tried that. I can fetch http urls without problem, but fail everytime with https urls. So i guess my server cannot make outbound requests on port 443.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have shell access on the box, you can simply try one of:

1) "wget http://www.google.com" (should create a file named index.html containing the source of the google main page)

2) "telnet google.com 80", which should produce some output indicating you're connected to google.com.  Try typing "GET /" followed by return.  You should see the google home page code fly by.

If you don't have shell access, do what derobert suggested, use php's built-in curl functions and try to make a connection.