# SSL certificates missing?

Tags: php, ssl, parse-platform, xampp, ssl-certificate

I'm messing with parse (parse.com) and when I run the following I get a fatal error. The code I am running is taken directly from the parse.com intro to the PHP SDK.

I am running XAMPP on Windows 10.

Do I need to run my scripts through https or am I really missing some SSL certs somewhere? How do I get it to work?

Error:

```html
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\php\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php:284
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\php\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(1037): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', '/1/classes/Test...', NULL, '{"foo":"bar"}', false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\php\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(947): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseObject), false)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\php\test.php(15): Parse\ParseObject->save()
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\php\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php on line 284
```

And the PHP snippet:

```js
require("./vendor/autoload.php");

use Parse\ParseClient;

ParseClient::initialize('secret', 'reallysecret', 'ubersecret');

use Parse\ParseObject;

$testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");
$testObject->save();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many duplicate questions to this and some slightly different answers.

It's not a parse.com issue, but your local PHP is not configured correctly.

One is to disable `curl`'s SSL verification, which is bad.
The other is to set your correct certificate path in `php.ini`.

You can download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to cacert.pem file. 
And in your `php.ini` set

```
curl.cainfo = "c:/youroflder/cacert.pem"
```

this cacert.pem file is not guaranteed to be safe, but you can generate your own using different tools.

Helpful answer: [How can I set CURLOPT_CAINFO globally for PHP on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694787/how-can-i-set-curlopt-cainfo-globally-for-php-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dan. I will look into this tomorrow.