# PHP cURL certificate error

Tags: php, curl, certificate

I'm attempting to add a custom `cer`-certificate to my PHP cURL request, but I keep getting this error:

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /path/to/my/cert.cer
  CApath: none
```

All I've found about this error is that:

1. **The path is relative.**
   As you can see, I've supplied an absolute path.
2. **The path is erroneous.**
   I've tried to `var_dump(file_exists($certLocation));`, which gives me `true`, so this is not the case.
3. **The permissions on the file are incorrect.**
   I've set the permissions to `777` for debugging purposes. Error remains.
4. **The path to the file doesn't have `+x`-permissions somewhere in the chain.**
   I've set this as well, ensuring that the entire path from root has `+x`-permissions, and still no luck.

I'm at a loss here, having tried everything I can find, and fact is, *I don't even understand what the error actually means.* What is a `verify location`? All I can understand is that there's an error with loading the file.

Any light shed on this is greatly appreciated. See code example below.

Thanks.

Code I use:

```
<?php

$oCurl = curl_init($this->baseUrl);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connectionTimeout);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/tmp/cert.cer");
```

Error:

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /tmp/cert.cer
  CApath: none
```

Comment: Your *.cer file has correct user and group set? Same as your script, that is accessing it?

Comment: Check the `curl.cainfo` value on your `php.ini`, if you're able to modify it change to `curl.cainfo=/tmp/cert.cer`

Comment: @Helge Hmm, are you sure that your `/tmp/cert.cer` is a CA(Certificate Authority) or a CA bundle, and not just a self signed certificate? if you type this command: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /tmp/cert.cer` can you see any `CA:TRUE` string in the output? what about the `Issuer` and `Subject` fields, are they the same?

Comment: Paladin, Yeah, I checked that as well. Owner is same as script execution user. Pedro, For various reasons, I'd like to keep this one bundled and expressively used in this script. @godvsdeity You got something! =D This is the output of your command: 10144:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström that's an unexpected output. Isn't your `/tmp/cert.cer` a PEM formatted certificate? what's the output of `file /tmp/cert.cer`?

Comment: @godvsdeity Yeah, I understand. It's a binary file. I haven't seen the `.cer`-extension before, but I read online that it should be a compound PEM certificate.

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström oh, I think that I understand what kind of file you have; this command should read it properly now: `openssl x509 -in /tmp/cert.cer -inform der -text -noout`, check if it is a CA certificate; my guess is that the `cer` you are trying to use is not a CA or CA-bundle, or if it is, then it is not the CA which signed the certificate used on the url you try to connect to.

Comment: @godvsdeity You are absolutely right. Seems the `.cer`-file was in `der`-format. The following command properly converted it and made it work: `openssl x509 -inform der -in cert.cer -outform pem -out cert.pem`. Please write an answer so I can mark it as solving the problem and give you the credit =) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström oh, i was busy writing the answer, didn't notice that you commented here :) ignore my last line from answer, you have a proper CA after all xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CURLOPT_CAINFO](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) is used in conjunction with [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html)

`CURLOPT_CAINFO` should be set to a CA or CA-bundle in PEM format. I managed to track the curl code which triggers this error and this is what I found:

in [curl/openssl.c](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/69b89050d4b824b54449df907bb9f23f80a3c382/lib/vtls/openssl.c#L1924):

```
if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(connssl->ctx,
                                   data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAFILE],
                                   data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAPATH])) {
  if(data->set.ssl.verifypeer) {
    /* Fail if we insist on successfully verifying the server. */
    failf(data, "error setting certificate verify locations:\n"
          "  CAfile: %s\n  CApath: %s",
          data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAFILE]?
          data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAFILE]: "none",
          data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAPATH]?
          data->set.str[STRING_SSL_CAPATH] : "none");
    return CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE;
  }
  ...
```

Apparently the call on `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` returns `0` and combined with the fact of having `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` set to `1` it triggers the error.

`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` is a function from openssl library, and according to the documentation([SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html)), the following statements should be taken into consideration:

"If CAfile is not NULL, it points to a file of CA certificates in **PEM** format."

"The CAfile is processed on execution of the SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() function."

"0 - The operation failed because CAfile and CApath are NULL or the processing at one of the locations specified failed." under **RETURN VALUES** section

---

You could try to convert your `cer` to a `pem` using the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in /tmp/cert.cer -inform der -outform pem -out /tmp/cert.pem
```

but I can't guarantee that this will work, because I'm not sure if you even have a proper CA or CA bundle file.

Comment: Yup, problem was that the `.cer`-file was in `der`-format. Running the command supplied to convert it from `der` to `pem` made everything work properly. Many thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

If your PHP installation doesn't have an up-to-date CA root certificate bundle, download the one at the curl website and save it on your server:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Then set a `path` to it in your `php.ini` file, e.g. on Windows:

```
curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem
```

---

**NOTE:**
Turning off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` allows man in the middle (MITM) attacks, which you don't want!

---

SRC1 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064903/797495
SRC2 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457