# OpenIDenabled PHP library with Google Openid

Tags: openid, google-openid

I am using JanRain OpenID Library PHP.
I am trying out the consumer example in /example/consumer.
Services like Google (or Yahoo) are not working, while other's like myopenid.com, blogger are working.

My PHPinfo says that cURL and OpenSSL is enabled.
Note that I also tried using LightOpenID Library (gitorious.org/lightopenid) which works with Google. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on server with php safe_mode On, it requires cURL. So I cannot use on all servers.

JanRain's Library works on the server but not with Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Janrain's PHP-OpenID and Google/Yahoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992682/janrains-php-openid-and-google-yahoo)

Comment: See my post here. I have given the code and explanation ! <br>
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179193/php-lightopenid-how-to-fetch-account-data-from-provider/5270929#5270929](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179193/php-lightopenid-how-to-fetch-account-data-from-provider/5270929#5270929)

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have cURL, so dependency on it shouldn't be a problem.

LightOpenID will work in safe_mode if you comment [this line](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/openid.php#line104)(at least it works for me). It won't follow Location http header then, but I don't know any server which uses it.

Anyway, safe_mode is deprecated, so you should avoid servers where it's enabled.