# How to use OpenID on my website

Tags: php, openid

I am using OpenID in our website but yahoo id is not verified. And from other OpenID I am not getting user detail so that I can store in the database.

Comment: have you already gone through http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe ?

Comment: Check this link about Simple OpenID PHP Class:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3290-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-OpenID-single-sign-on.html

Comment: See my post here. I have given the code and explanation ! <br>
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179193/php-lightopenid-how-to-fetch-account-data-from-provider/5270929#5270929](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179193/php-lightopenid-how-to-fetch-account-data-from-provider/5270929#5270929)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [LightOpenID](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/).

Another answer suggested SimpleOpenID, but it supports only OpenID 1.1 (so you won't be able to authenticate with google, for example), and is designed for PHP4.